# SQL SERVER Insert New Column Values for every row of existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing table of customers. I want to add a NEW row for each customer based on ALL of the services our company offers.

AS IS:

```
Customer - ID
Freddy - 123
```

TO BE:

```
Customer - ID - Service
Freddy - 123 - Serv1
Freddy - 123 - Serv2
Freddy - 123 - Serv3
```

etc ...

Right now I have been working with below but it has not given desired output:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (Service) 
VALUES ('Serv1'), ('Serv2'), ('Serv3')
```

Comment: IMO this isn't wise.  Duplicating customer records is generating redundant data.  Wouldn't you be better off having an associative table between customer and services that you populate with this data instead of DUPLICATING customer data?  You're decreasing the normal form of the database by doing this, and if it's an existing application, potentially causing harm to the existing system when the system may not be expecting duplicate records for the same customer.

Comment: @xQbert agreed 100%. I am just attempting to make a document I can proliferate to business users so they can populate rates for each service per customer per variables such as location, coverage, etc ... I have a normalized version of the customer master which I will associate to a normalized version of the services table once complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some sort of `JOIN`, in this case a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.Customer, c.Id, v.s
FROM Customers c CROSS JOIN
     (VALUES ('Serv1'), ('Serv2'), ('Serv3')) v(s);
```

However, it doesn't make sense to insert this into the original table.  That table only has two columns, but you seem to want a third one.

Comment: many thanks, this worked perfectly. The original table had more than two columns, but I didn't want to spell all of them in the demo.

Answer (score 1):

you have only two column so create third one.

go to table>>design>>and create the third row called Services

now do this:

```
UPDATE Customers
SET service='serv1'
WHERE Customer='Freddy '
```

Remember:
The WHERE clause specifies which record or records that should be updated. If you omit the WHERE clause, all records will be updated!

Comment: I understand where you are coming from but for this exercise but I want all record to be updated in this case. As I just explained above, I am trying to create a template to pass to business users with intentions to normalize after I have their input.